# How to fix tags in Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

I've just switched over to Ubuntu 22.04. In Rhythmbox I've installed about two dozen albums, and Rhythmbox shows "no title (42)" and "unknown (90)." Apparently this is from a bug in gstreamer which is at least ten years old. I've installed BrainzPicard, and this is what I've got left after running it. I really don't want to spend several days looking these things up and manually entering the data. What can I do to fix these?

Answer (score 0):

MusicBrainz Picard does not do a good job at automatically fetching music file tags. You end up with lots of errors. My favorite applications for tagging songs are EasyTag (`sudo apt install easytag`) and ExFalso (`sudo apt install exfalso`) which are in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To save time I use both of these applications.

- If you have several albums by the same artist or with the same genre, EasyTag can tag all of them at once which saves a lot of time.
- ExFalso can automatically generate the track number and song title tags from the titles of a batch of songs from the same album. This is also a big time saver compared to manually entering the data one song at a time.